# javascript window.open url + json var

Tags: javascript, prestashop-1.6

What I am trying to accomplish is to open a url(base) with an added var at the end.

```
window.open(https://vipparcel.com/package/detailed/ + json.id[0])
```

This was written by someone else to just display an image but I need it to pop more detailed info.

I DO NOT know javascript so its like a child poking at a dead animal here.

I have exhausted my normal go to's and then some to find more info on this.

the url  would look like https://vipparcel.com/package/detailed/000000 if the info passes correctly.

Anything pointing me in the right direction would be extremely helpful!

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Add quotes around the url window.open(' h t t p s ://vipparcel.com/package/detailed/' + json.id[0]); EDIT: sorry about the spaces in h t t p but otherwise stackoverflow would actually parse it as a url

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. If you want more detailed information, then you'll need to get that information from somewhere. That would, presumably, be a case of writing PHP (since Prestashop is written in PHP). I don't know why you mentioned Java at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var myurl = "https://vipparcel.com/package/detailed/" + json.id[0];
window.open(myurl);
```

Answer (score 1):

What errors are you getting? Looks like you're just missing quotations. If that's not the case, is `json` an object with an array of `id`s? If instead it's an array of objects with an `id` property, the following should work:

window.open('https://vipparcel.com/package/detailed/' + json[0].id)

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
window.open('https://vipparcel.com/package/detailed/' + json.id[0]);
```

it's looking for a string to open the website by. You weren't passing a string through to it.